# Conditional compilation depending on compiler version

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm looking for a way to implement something like this:

```
#if CSHARP_COMPILER_IS_FOR_CSHARP_6_OR_HIGHER
    foo?.Bar();
#else
    if (foo != null)
    {
        foo.Bar();
    }
#endif
```

Of course, I could define a conditional compilation symbol by myself, but it isn't suitable.

Is there any built-in constant?
The questions I found are rather old. Maybe, the things were changed to the best?

Comment: No, from what I know they didn't change anything :-) You could perhaps do a little magic inside the csproj to define the constants...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The generated IL is going to be the same, and the code just became (a lot) less readable...

Comment: @jeroenh: this is temporary "patch", while moving to VS 2015/C#6. I need ability to compile the source code using both C#5 and C#6, making some APIs obsolete for new version of code, and later just remove "old" portions of code.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead for little added benefit. It's not that your C#5 code doesn't compile anymore under C#6... The painless route seems to me to delay the use of C#6 specifics until you have moved completely...

Comment: @jeroenh: well, I'd agree with you, if the problem was only with single method and `?.` operator... But this is just a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, from what I know they didn't change anything :-)

You could perhaps do a little magic inside the csproj to define the constants... but it is complex...

There is no property that specifies directly the version of the CSC... There is a property (`$(LangVersion)`) that specifies the version of the language standard required... but it is normally set to `default` so "the maximum the compiler supports"...

Or you could look at the path of the CSC compiler... It is stored in the `CscToolPath` or, if that is empty, in the `MsBuildToolsPath`. From there perhaps you can discern the version of the CSC.